# efficient Lucene index for boosting queries based on citations and years

Tags: lucene

I'm building an index of research articles, each of which has fields like the title, authors, abstract text, year of publication, IDs of articles in the bibliography, etc. I need to efficiently combine some queries that are based on the citation links between articles.

**EDIT:** In a typical example, I might be looking for articles with:

```
+(title:preterm abstract:preterm)
```

But I want to boost articles that have been cited many times. So for each article `A`, I can collect all the articles that cite an article with a query like `+bibliography:A`, and then index the number of such articles in a new `citationCount` field that I add to `A`. Then I can add a citation count boost to queries using a FunctionQuery, an IntFieldSource and a BoostedQuery, to get something like:

```
+(title:preterm abstract:preterm)
+boost(int(citationCount), const(0.1))
```

I also want to boost an article based on the terms used in the articles that cite it. So, as above, I can collect all the articles that cite `A` with a query like `bibliography:A`, and then index all of their title and abstract terms as new `citingTitles` and `citingAbstracts` fields that are added to `A`. I can then boost queries based on citing terms by creating a query like:

```
+(title:preterm abstract:preterm)
+boost((citingTitles:preterm citingAbstracts:preterm), const(0.5))
```

This all works fine until I need a year restriction. For example, I might need to only boost the query based on citations that occurred before 1990. Basically I need something like:

```
+(title:preterm abstract:preterm)
+boost(int(citationCountBefore1990), const(0.1))
+boost((citingTitlesBefore1990:preterm citingAbstractsBefore1990:preterm), const(0.5))
```

But following this approach literally and creating each of the `XXXBeforeXXX` fields (e.g. using queries like `+bibliography:A +year:[* TO XXX]`) would require massive duplication - for example, all the terms in the abstracts citing an article would be repeated in `citingAbstractsBeforeXXX`, `citingAbstractsBeforeXXX+1`, `citingAbstractsBeforeXXX+2`, etc.

How can I avoid this duplication, but still keep my queries fast?

**EDIT:** Maybe there's some way to do this with a [query time join](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/join/org/apache/lucene/search/join/JoinUtil.html)? The problem feels a little join-like, but I don't immediately see how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what does "compare user term(s) query <..> against the abstracts of all articles that cited article A before 2003" mean, but for the dates (first example), I'd do the following (pseudo code):

Example documents:

```
id:article_1
creation_date:1990
bibliography:<none>

id:article_2
creation_date:1991
bibliography:article_1

id:article_3
creation_date:2000
bibliography:article_1,article_2
```

Then to query for articles which are quoting article 1 before 1996, you query like this:

```
bibliography:article_1 AND creation_date:[* TO 1996]
```

This would return `id:article_2` and should not be expensive.

Comment: Sorry for not presenting my problem more clearly. I've rewritten the question using your query style above to show what I'm trying to do. Basically, there's one more level of indirection - I need to use the result of a query like `bibliography:article_1 AND creation_date:[* TO 1996]` as a boosting factor in another query.